# Winforms: Cancel/Prevent Scrolling Event When Swipe Outside of DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, events, scroll, touch

I have a DataGridView with a usercontrol scrollbar to the right of it. When swiping inside the DataGridView, I get scroll events in the DataGridView which works fine (from the swiping). Unfortunately, if I swipe over the custom scrollbar immediately after swiping over the DataGridControl (outside of the DataGridView), the DataGridView still gets scroll events from the swiping. I would like to prevent these scroll events in the DataGridView when the swiping (i.e. thinking mouse location) occurs outside of the DataGridView control. Instead the scrollbar outside of the DataGridView should be getting clicked and scrolled. I can manage the scrolling from the custom scrollbar separately. Ideas appreciated. I do not see an easy way to cancel the scroll event (within the event itself). Thanks for looking and any help definitely appreciated. I did not see an answer in stackoverflow.

**For Dmitry's Answer (could not put in comment since too long):** I tried it, but getting an argumentoutofrange exception "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.\r\nParameter name: index".    at System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.SharedRow(Int32 rowIndex)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.ScrollRowsByHeight(Int32 height)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.set_VerticalOffset(Int32 value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewVScrolled(Object sender, ScrollEventArgs se)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBar.OnScroll(ScrollEventArgs se)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBar.DoScroll(ScrollEventType type)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBar.WmReflectScroll(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBar.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam). Ideas and thanks?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can try to handle DataGridView's `MouseLeave` event to hide scrollbars `dataGridView1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None;` and then return them back in the `MouseEnter` event handler.

Comment: See edited question above, since could not fit in this comment. Thanks!

Comment: Stack trace is good, but where is the code in which exception was raised?

Comment: For source it indicates mscorlib. The exception itself breaks immediately after an Application.Run call. The targetsite is at get_Item with Data being at System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal. The count for Keys and Values is 0. I hope that helps. If something else would help, just let me know. Thanks

Comment: I think you have an error in the custom scrollbar's `Scroll` event handler. It seems you are trying to scroll to the row, which index is out of the range. Please verify it or provide its source code.

Comment: As a guess, maybe the exception is thrown before rows has been added to the `DataGridView`. If true, you should check this in the `Scroll` event handler.

Comment: Good work. I now only do work in the scroll event handler if there are rows in the DataGridView. I am off to look at your proposal for the main solution. Thanks. More to follow.

Comment: Will need to work on this later in the weekend when more time. Ran into another exception. Thanks again.

Comment: Any other ideas for disabling the scrollbar or quickly getting out of swipe mode? Getting out of swipe mode when out of the datagridview would work since then it would be able to do a different scrollbar drag. The swipe would not interfere. Currently, the exception occurs less frequently, but it occurs. Thanks again. I am back on this now. Thanks for looking and if you have any ideas.